# Angular override ALT+ESC

Tags: angular

As you all know ALT+ESC is a shortcut that closes the window.
I'm trying to override that shortcut so that it instead closes an open dialog in my application, using a directive.
Code goes into directive, but at the same time closes the whole application (not only dialog). How can I prevent application from closing?

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';dialog.component';

@Directive({
    selector: '[test-directive]'
  })
  export class TestDirective {
    constructor() {}
    
    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) 
    onKeyDown(e) {
      if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 18) {          
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        closeDialog();
      }         
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that... Very strange idea to use browser hotkeys (even if u can override them, guess u cant actually) -- why not just use 'Esc' hotkey?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov this is not the question.

Answer (score 1):

something like this works properly in Chrome:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
 handleHotkey(event: KeyboardEvent){
  ...
  //Do Something 
  ...
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

and

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    event.preventDefault()
  })
</script>
```

Comment: propably also in every other Chromium based browser. not quite sure about IE11 to be honest.

Comment: not working for me, web application is still closing. Any ideas of improvement?

Comment: @chichi what browser are you using? can you also share your markup how you implemented the event?

Comment: I'm using Chrome.
Since it's a directive I just add 'test-directive' to the dialog element.
How does your markup implementation look like?

Comment: You can utilize the fact that events bubble up the DOM tree. In your Angular code, listen to events  by attaching an event listener to document. In the global part of the page, simply listen to window instead of document. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you but it is still not working for me.